# pyrax cloud monitoring checks test

Tags: python, rackspace-cloud, rackspace, pyrax

I have created the entities and checks using Rackspace Cloud Monitoring APIs now I need to run/test the checks so I can feed the values every 60 seconds or so in our existing monitoring system and can trigger alert or mainly report on the data.

I am able to use via command line utility raxmon-checks-test and raxmon-checks-test-existing but I could not find a direct way of doing this using pyrax module. May be this can be done using requests instance of pyrax.cloudmonitoring but I couldn't find any good examples. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent to `raxmon-checks-test` is to use `create_check` and pass in `test_only=True`.  At this time there is no direct equivalent to `raxmon-checks-test-existing`

Here is the docstring provided in the `create_check` method:

> Creates a check on the entity with the specified attributes. The
>   'details' parameter should be a dict with the keys as the option name,
>   and the value as the desired setting.
>
> If the 'test_only' parameter is True, then the check is not created;
>   instead, the check is run and the results of the test run returned. If
>   'include_debug' is True, additional debug information is returned.
>   According to the current Cloud Monitoring docs:
>       "Currently debug information is only available for the
>       remote.http check and includes the response body."

The docs for `create_check` can be found at https://github.com/rackspace/pyrax/blob/master/docs/cloud_monitoring.md#create-the-check although they are currently lacking information about `test_only`.